# Magento model ends up with Invalid method xxx::beginTransaction(Array()

Tags: magento

I am trying to write data to a table in the database. I finally set up my model but I can not write data to it.

I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid method Turnkeye_Adminform_Model_Mysql4_Iaso::beginTransaction(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(313): Varien_Object->__call('beginTransactio...', Array)
#1 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(313): Turnkeye_Adminform_Model_Mysql4_Iaso->beginTransaction()
#2 E:\projects\magento\app\code\community\Turnkeye\Adminform\controllers\Adminhtml\AdminformController.php(47): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#3 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Turnkeye_Adminform_Adminhtml_AdminformController->saveAction()
#4 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#5 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 E:\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 E:\projects\magento\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 E:\projects\magento\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Because of the amount of code I have posted it to pastebin:

[controllers/Adminhtml/AdminformController.php](http://pastebin.com/n7bbHPzd)

[etc/config.xml](http://pastebin.com/8r8gvvUh)

[etc/adminhtml.xml](http://pastebin.com/pTsQ9XzH)

[Model/iaso.php](http://pastebin.com/TZcVhz0t)

[Model/Mysql4/Iaso.php](http://pastebin.com/4era02v2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because your code defines

```
Turnkeye_Adminform_Model_Mysql4_Iaso extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

which is wrong.

You need to extend from a *resource* model, that is from a class, which is extending the abstract class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`. That's where `beginTransaction()` is defined.

Usually this is done by extending from `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract`, because there are some more methods standard mySQL resources use in Magento and these are defined thru:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract extends
   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract extends
       Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract
```

So changing your definition to

```
Turnkeye_Adminform_Model_Mysql4_Iaso extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
```

should bring you back on the right track.

Comment: You just saved my evening! Thanks a lot! Totally missed it.